# Rails 4 + MySQL - ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I faced this issue yesterday and still trying to google or browser threads here on SO.

The disturbing thing is that my application is currently in beta and is used by only not more than 20 users, so we cannot talk about a serious workload.

I've been looking for possible reasons and the fastest fix seems to be increasing the `pool` value in the `database.yml` file - after switching it from `5` to `30` this issue  gone, however it doesn't seems to be a satisfying solution, because it's just pushing the problem ahead.

I found an article where the author pointed out that this reason is caused by executing SQL queries out of the controller - in views, models and helpers.

I am rewriting part of my app this way - even though I cannot fully remove all queries from all helpers and models, I am reducing these queries from views.

So, the question - is calling an association in a view considered as an SQL query? Something like:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  %div= user.car.name
```

Also - one more question - what other reason can be behind this error message? How can one avoid it?

The used stack: Rails 4, MySQL 5.5, Unicorn, Ubuntu 12.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes the `user.car.name` will execute an query which will select the car name from cars table matching to the user's id.

Comment: Why don't you use caching if possible in your application?

Comment: Do you start threads manually in your app?

Comment: also queries inside models is completely normal. Too much db logic in helpers/views is not a great idea, but not because it would cause this problem.

Comment: @Deep - I'll check how to use caching for this case.

Comment: @FrederickCheung - I don't do anything with them. I got that error yesterday and still don't know how to properly figure it out. Increasing the `pool` value temporarily helped, but this error can occur any other day as I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Typically this error happens if database connections aren't returned to the pool, and starting threads (other than the thread your web request runs in) can do that if you don't clean up the connections. If you make queries from middleware that runs before the connection management middleware that might also do it

Comment: @FrederickCheung - thank you for your reply. I found this article - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#multi-process-servers - is this what are you talking about (sorry, I am not experienced in Rails this deep)? Putting that code in to `config/unicorn.rb` would clean up the connection?

Comment: That is the right sort of area. Although to be honest I thought omitting that for your unicorn.rb would result in a different sort of error

Comment: I edited the code the way as is mentioned in the article. Deployed without any problem. Though, how can I actually verify the code is working? The thing is I only copied there the code, and I am not sure everything is correctly set up.